# Ubuntu 14.04 tomcat 7 iso8859-8 encoding mysql utf8

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, tomcat7, iso-8859-2

Hi I'm having encoding problem.
I have Ubuntu 14.04 OS, Tomcat 7 installed encoding configured as iso8859-8.
My Webapp parse XML file and save the data at MySql DB.(UTF8)

When parsing the XML i can see the correct data but after saving the data it's become 
as   ?????. (The language is Hebrew).

Anyone encounter this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

Comment: Nop ,I saw this one and tried it before asking here. :(

Comment: solved by mysql conf file :[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8