# Struts2 s:url params with special characters not getting decoded properly

Tags: java, struts2, character-encoding, url-encoding

I'm having some issues including parameters with special characters in a `<s:url/>` `struts2` tag.

Params inside a `<s:form/>`, either as hidden or explicit fields are behaving just fine although some can have special characters, but the trouble comes when I try to append any param which contains special characters (in this case 'é') to a `struts2` URL and trigger an action with it.

This is the `<s:url/>`:

```
<s:url var="urlRegular" action="fetchUserServices" escapeAmp="false">
    <s:param name="username" value="%{username}" />
    <s:param name="type" value="%{type}"/>
</s:url>
```

Debugging with Eclipse, whenever the method `fetchUserServices` is called, the parameter `username`, which should be **'cInglés'**, appears to be stored as **'cInglÃ©s'** , and thus I guess it's not decoded properly from `UTF-8` comming from the `HTTP` request.

Inside the `HTTP` request I can see the parameter `username` is encoded and sent like this:

```
myPath/fetchUserServices.action?username=cIngl%C3%A9s&type=1
```

So, it appears to me that it's successfully sent to the controller from the view..

I have also tried specifying the `username` parameter like this, but with no luck:

```
<s:url var="urlRegular" action="fetchUserServices" escapeAmp="false">
    <s:param name="username" >
      <s:property value="%{username}" />
    </s:param>
    <s:param name="type" value="%{type}"/>
</s:url>
```

this just changes the way it behaves, and if I use that notation, the param is now encoded on the url like this (`XHR` request):

```
myPath/fetchUserServices.action?username=%5BcIngl%26eacute%3Bs%5D&type=1
```

And my `fetchUserServices` method receives it this way: **cIngl&\eacute;s** *(without the '\', I had to use it because markdown language used here decodes it as cInglés)*.

At this point I'm a little bit lost, all my pages specify `UTF-8` encoding and params with special characters aren't an issue when they go inside a `<s:form />` tag.

How can I fix this and have my parameter decoded on my `fetchUserServices` method?

---

**Question update:** Tried this solution [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/How+to+support+UTF-8+URIEncoding+with+Tomcat) which suggests using the `Spring character encoding filter` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Using tomcat?  https://struts.apache.org/docs/how-to-support-utf-8-uriencoding-with-tomcat.html

Comment: @AleksandrM  I'll definitely try this, but I don't understand why parameters get decoded successfully when inside `<s:form />` tags (hidden or not). If it was a ´tomcat´ issue, wouldn't them have to fail decoding too?

Comment: @AleksandrM didn't work.. parameter is still decoded as I declared on my question.. Maybe this has to do with the nature of the request. It's made using `AJAX` for loading the contents of a dinamic tab and it aims to the `URL` I posted on my question.

Comment: POST parameters are not affected by uriencoding. Can you try with plain link w/o ajax to eliminate this part.

Comment: The parameters are encoded by default , but if you not output them to the response you can disable this parameter.

Comment: thanks for your help @AleksandrM and Roman , always there for us ;). I've finally managed to solve the issue and posted an answer to help others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to get it to work. All I had to do was to specify the URI encoding in the connector at port 8080, where my tomcat handles the requests.

The version I'm using is `tomcat7`, and all I had to do was to add `URIEncoding = "UTF-8"` so now it looks like this:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Also, it is possible to specify a character encoding filter, for instance, the one provided by `Spring`. All you have to do is add this as **the first** filter in your `web.xml`:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

This was not mandatory for me, as **only** stating the URI encoding worked out, didn't need to include the filter too, but I have read over the net that it can help.

---

**Regarding the lack of understanding** why it would work using `POST` requests and don't with the `GET` ones, I've learnt that `POST` requests specify the character encoding on their own, while the others don't. Quoted from [tomcat apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding):

> **What is the default character encoding of the request or response
>   body?**
>
> If a character encoding is not specified, the Servlet specification
>   requires that an encoding of ISO-8859-1 is used. The character
>   encoding for the body of an HTTP message (request or response) is
>   specified in the Content-Type header field. An example of such a
>   header is Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 which explicitly
>   states that the default (ISO-8859-1) is being used.

And finally, there is [very elaborated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138950/3736964) that addresses this issue and can help if you need more advanced help (it covers the point of using `mysql` and having the need of allowing `UTF-8` decoding too)