# Mapping servlet to Hebrew (UTF-8) URL pattern

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, utf-8

I am on a windows OS.
Using tomcat 8.
IDE - Netbeans 8.
JDK1.8.0_05

I am trying to specify a hebrew url pattern for certain servlets.
(I have tried both by setting the `Urlpattern` attribute of the `@webservlet` annotation and by placing in the `web.xml` file).

The Hebrew mapping doesn't work.
I check to see what the mappings look like while Tomcat is running (By using the MBeans tab of JConsole) and the Hebrew url is displayed as gibberish (specifically, question marks).

I have tried:

- Adding -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to netbeans.conf file.
- Changing windows Locale to Hebrew.
- Using the URLEncoded version of the url in the pattern (this is also displayed as gibberish symbols in JConsole).
- Also tried entering the URL in its encoded form into the address bar (eg: localhost:8080/test/%D7%A2%D7%91).
- Checked the encoding of the Servlet files in notepad, they save as UTF-8 (after making the first change described in this list).
- I have a filter on all url patterns (ie: "/*") that sets the character encoding of the request to UTF-8 (Also tried Apache's `SetCharacterEncodingFilter`)

Any suggestions on how I can map to a hebrew (UTF-8) url with tomcat, netbeans, java, windows setup?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to configure tomcat to understand UTF8 ( Defautl I think  charset=ISO-8859-1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Comment: As well u can try to configure JVM for tomcat. Set -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  in startup.bat

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your application server to encode request parameters in utf-8. Since you are using Tomcat, that would be setting  `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in your conf/server.xml file. Here's what it should look like:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
 maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
 .......
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

Comment: URIEncoding defaults to UTF-8 in tomcat 8

Comment: If server is configured with "strict servlet compliance" on, the default value of URIEncoding attribute of connectors is "ISO-8859-1", the same as in older versions of Tomcat. I am guessing that's not the case. Still you might want to make sure that org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE system property is NOT set to true.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Write a Charset filter that will control all requests and responses:
   Reference: https://github.com/edendramis/freemarker-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/edendramis/config/CharsetFilter.java

   ```
    package charsetFilter.classes;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

   public class CharsetFilter implements Filter{
       private String encoding;

       public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
               encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
               if( encoding==null ) encoding="UTF-8";
       }

       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain       next)
       throws IOException, ServletException{
           // Respect the client-specified character encoding
           // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
               if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
               request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
               /**
           * Set the default response content type and encoding
           */
           response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
               next.doFilter(request, response);
       }

           public void destroy(){}
   }`
   ```
2. Add this filter to web.xml

   ```
    <filter>
           <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
           <filter-class>charsetFilter.classes.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
               <init-param>
                   <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
                   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
               </init-param>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
3. Write some HTML code e.g.:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fi">
           <head>
               <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />`

4. Use the following in your servlet:

   ```
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   ```
5. For getting String:
   `String input = new String(request.getParameter("foo").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf-8");
   String input = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("keyWord"), "UTF-8");
   System.out.println(input);`

For URL:

```
String str = "$ome UTF-8 text £900";
String url = "http://your-domain.com/url?p=" + URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I edited the question. I have also tried (I had already had one set up) setting up a filter to set the character encoding of the `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: The rest of these deal with character encoding for displaying content. No? Not URLs. My UTF-8 content displays fine (including query strings).

Comment: Have you tried URLEncoding.encode? I have updated my answer

Comment: You are encoding the parameters. I have no issue with the parameters. I have an issue with the url itself, specifically, the servlet path.

Comment: @BalusC you are wrong at this time. I never plagiarized answer from any post. Check with open eyes my answer and the answer you referred.

Comment: @BalusC remove your bad comments against my post and please make a little search before rewarding plagiarism to other work

Comment: None of this all explains/solves OP's concrete problem. Point 5 is absolutely not recommended as it's a workaround not a solution. Next time try reproducing OP's concrete problem yourself instead of making guesses.

Comment: Read OP's comments that he given against your post and then said something to someone else. A fat down vote to your post