# ISO-8859-1 encoded URL can't be correctly decoded by Servlet in Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, servlets, urlencode

I have a Servlet as simple as this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("processedName", request.getParameter("name"));
        request.setAttribute("processedQueryString", request.getQueryString());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

My `index.jsp` is like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="MyServlet" method="get">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    After: <%=request.getAttribute("processedName") %>
    <br>
    Query String: <%=request.getAttribute("processedQueryString") %>
</body>
</html>
```

If I type `Thomás` in the form and submit it, `Thom?s` is printed.

Both the URL in browser and the query string in JSP show `name=Thom%E1s`

The browser is correctly encoding the ISO-8859-1 `á` char as `%E1`, but for some reason the `.getParameter` is not decoding it correctly.

I've seen tons of posts like this here when people try to submit non ISO-8859-1 chars (unlike `á`). Shouldn't Tomcat 8 use ISO-8859-1 as default for decoding?

Strangely, if I put `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in my form, it works. If I change the method to `method="post"` it works. If I mix both the `accept-charset="UTF-8"` and `method="post"` it doesn't work (but now `ThomÃ¡s` is printed!).

It's as if Tomcat is waiting UTF-8 in get method and ISO-8859-1 in post method.

Comment: Check the guide in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default URIEncoding in tomcat 8 is UTF-8 except if the property `org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE` is set to `true`, then it is ISO-8859-1.

In your case you can try to add the following :

```
 URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
```

in your `server.xml` file to the Connector element.

See the [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) for all details.