# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I am writing an app that is going to heavily use utf-8 encoding.
For the server I'm using java servlets, and for the UI I'm using Java Servlets with jsp and javascript.
So, after ignoring the gibberish for some time, I decided to solve the utf-8 encoding issue. 
While looking for a solution, I made a filter class
I followed @cosoant's answer here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps` up until "MySQL database and tables" (excluding), because I am still developing with `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />` in my `persistence.xml`.
Then I understood that mysql's utf8 is not exactly the rest of the world's utf 8, so I changed characterEncoding in persistence.xml to: `<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8mb4" />` 
Also, following this : `https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4` link I upgraded MySqlServer, and added:

> [client]
>   default-character-set = utf8mb4
>
> [mysql] default-character-set = utf8mb4
>
> [mysqld] character-set-client-handshake = FALSE character-set-server =
>   utf8mb4 collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

to `mysql.cnf`.
I restarted mysql by typing `sudo service mysql restart` in terminal and made sure that when I go into mysql command line UI and type: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` this:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

is what I get.
I also switched the `com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar` with `mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar` .

And still, I get the above error each time I try to access the DB.
this is my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at tests.Test.main(Test.java:38)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl.postInitialization(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl.initializeProperties(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:2519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializeDriverProperties(ConnectionImpl.java:3140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:763)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.D    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at tests.Test.main(Test.java:38)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl.postInitialization(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl.initializeProperties(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:2519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializeDriverProperties(ConnectionImpl.java:3140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:763)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 30 moreelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
```

I think I got to the point where I'm stuck.
I'd appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this in the hibernate xml configuration file:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

Also make changes to the connection url as follows:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

The above changes were enough for me to upgrade from utf8 to utf8mb4 charset scheme.

As a side note I  would like to make one clarification that `UTF8` is the character encoding while `UTF8MB4` is a character set that MySQL supports. UTF8MB4 is a superset to UTF8. Refer this link for more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: That works properly! I found a problem in the connection url, as it fails.

Comment: Updating the connection URL to this solved my issue. 

                                                                                                                                                       

"db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true"                                                                                                                 

The connection Url in the given answer did not work.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, after 6 hours of trying, there are only 3 steps.

1. Change your column to utf8mb4 with utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
2. Change your table to utf8mb4 with utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
3. Use the latest MySQL Connector.(The most important one.)

```
//    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.3'
mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27
```

That's all. No need to change database encoding or collate. No need to change `jdbcUrl`. No need to add properties in `Hibernate`/`Spring` configuration.

This jdbc url is fine. No need to add/change any parameter. Just to make sure you're using UTF-8 encoding.

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.10:3306/db_name?characterEncoding=utf8
```

And there's no need to edit your ini/cnf file.

Here's the screenshot of the messages which are loaded from my database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me.
Rather than this, better you can remove all unprintable chars from string likewise in Java:

```java
str.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```