# How to persist text containing html emoji in mysql through hibernate

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, emoticons

I am adding the emojis using their html codes (example: & # 1 2 8 0 7 0 ; ) using a javascript function in a contenteditable html element which displays the emoji (example: )

I then retrieve the content of the element with

```
var content = el.innerText;
```

I add the content in a json

```
var myjson = {"content" : content};
```

I send the json through ajax with content-type being

```
application/json
```

In, the backend i convert the json to a pojo using Gson, then persist it in the database using hibernate

In the servlet, using system.out.println, the content displays as ð  in the db, a select query displays it as ð (with small numbers inside the rectangles)

I spent hours searching, setting the character set as utf8mb4 in the DB as well as the hibernate config file...example as described in the following links

[Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140583/caused-by-java-sql-sqlexception-unsupported-character-encoding-utf8mb4)

[How to store Emoji Character in MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database)

I'm a bit lost with it. My need is to persist a text containing emoji and be able to retrieve it(through hibernate or simple jdbc) and display it in a webpage.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: I cannot post an answer, because - clearly - you have many parts working together.  There are two primary points you have to keep in mind:  **POINT 1:** An `Emoji` is **not a character** - it is just a sequence of characters from the **UNICODE** character set.  An `Emoji` can be represented from as many as _5 16-bit characters_ lined up in a row.  **POINT 2:** Not all editors, text-viewers, and User Interfaces are capable of _rendering an `Emoji`_ - even though the characters themselves are all right in the `String`.

Comment: I have tried retrieving the text from the DB and just printing it on the webpage, I can see that it displays �\u009f\u0091\u0086 for one emoji...any idea on how to display the emoji on a webpage ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this at database level:

Modify databases, tables, and columns
Change the character set and collation properties of the databases, tables, and columns to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8.

## For each database:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

## For each table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

## For each column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Check the maximum length of columns and index keys

```
show VARIABLES like 'ver%'
```

SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character_set_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

====result should be====
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_general_ci
collation_server    utf8_general_ci

Repair and optimize all tables
For each table

```
REPAIR TABLE table_name; OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name; $ mysqlcheck -u root -p –auto-repair –optimize –all-databases
```

Try this at database level. Your problem might be linked to a database.

Comment: I like this answer too.  I gave an **upvote** - since you are facing the data-base side of the communication chain (which I don't do anymore - **SQL**).  I just want to add, though, that I think the smartest way to deal with it is to save the `Emjoi` using the **text `String`** (`"&#128070;"`) that is obtained via Java-Scipt using `"&#" + s.codePointAt(0) + ";";` because he intends to insert that same `Emoji` into another returned web-page.  In that case **he would not need to** change any of the character-encodings at the data-base level...  But there are multiple ways to deal with this...

Answer (score 0):

Here, i got flustered because of the **Java-Script** which I have gotten away from in the past while...  Play with this page, to see how `Emoji's` are represented.

**`CodePoint`** is not a change in ***representation***, it is a change in ***interpretation***...  There is simply not enough space to explain eveything about escape sequences and character representation in a single Stack Oveflow answer...  This is going to HiLite the major issues when retrieving an `Emoji` from an HTML Page.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Emoji</TITLE>
<SCRIPT TYPE='text/javascript'>
function show()
{
    // Prints the EMOJI ITSELF... (I can't enter that here)
    var s = document.getElementById("thediv").innerHTML;
    alert(s);

    // Prints characters:  � � 
    //
    // NOTE: The UNICODE characters (55357 and 56390) are unprintable
    //       Therefore the question mark (�) is printed
    var s2 = " ";
    for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) s2 = s2 + (s.charAt(i)) + ' ';
    alert(s2);
    
    // Prints Characters: 55357 56390 
    //
    // NOTE: This is guaranteed to be a number between 1 and 65,535
    //       which 2^16 - and UNICODE is a 16 bit space.
    var s3 = " ";
    for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) s3 = s3 + (s.charCodeAt(i)) + ' ';
    alert(s3);
    
    // Prints Characters: 128070 56390 
    //
    // NOTE: here, the SECOND NUMBER is IRRELEVANT... It is "incorporated" in the first..
    //       As mentioned, interpreting two characters in a row using
    //       CODE-POINT means, the second number and the first are "Chomped" together.
    // The second number is called the "High Surrogate"
    var s4 = " ";
    for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) s4 = s4 + (s.codePointAt(i)) + ' ';
    alert(s4);

    // Prints the String "&#128070;"
    //
    // YOU SHOULD PROBABLY BE SENDING THIS TO YOUR DATABASE...
    var s5 = "&#" + s.codePointAt(0) + ";";
    alert(s5);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<H1>Divider</H1>
<DIV ID="thediv">&#128070;</DIV>
<BR /><BR /><BUTTON onclick="show();">Click Me</BUTTON>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The above code will send the following java-script alerts:

`document.getElementById("thediv").innerHTML;`
[image: The rendered Emoji]

`s.charAt(i)`
[image: The individual characters]

`s.charCodeAt(i)`
[image: The Character Codes]

`s.codePointAt(i)`
[image: The Code points]

`"&#" + s.codePointAt(0) + ";";`
[image: The HTML Escaped Emoji]