# How to set the character encoding to UTF8 in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

**The problem:** I would like to set the encoding to UTF-8. Still, I have `Content-Type text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`
How can I do this? I followed the accepted answer in this question: [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

**Using:**

- FreeMarker
- Spring 5.0.2
- Ubuntu Linux 17.04
- Tomcat 8.5
- Java 9

**In `server.xml` Connector object:** `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`

**Inside HTML header:** `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` or `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />`

**Inside a class that implements WebMvcConfigurer:**

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freemarkerViewResolver()
{
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();

    resolver.setCache(true);
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    resolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    return resolver;
}
```

**Also:**

```
FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

**Using filter:**

```
public class CharsetFilter implements Filter
{

    private String encoding;

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");

        if (encoding == null)
        {
            encoding = "UTF-8";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if (null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
        {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        next.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Inside web.xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```