# JSP doesn't display cyrillic content?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

When I run JSP page with RequsetDispatcher it shows me the cyrillic content with "????...".

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
```

Here is what I tried:

I am using Apache Tomcat and I added that in the VM-options:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

In the beginning of the jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

In web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>utf-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <filter> 
        <filter-name>CharSet</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>encoding</param-name> 
            <param-value>utf-8</param-value> 
        </init-param> 
    </filter> 

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharSet</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In the connectors in tomcat configuration file conf/server.xml:

```
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

And it still doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it?

Edit: Fixed when I aded `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` in the Servlet method.

Comment: what application server are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is most probably related to the **application server** you are using.

*Please refer to this thread and try to solve your problem by changing your application-server configuration file to use UTF-8* -> [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138950/1970299)

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece was adding `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` in the beginning of the dopost method in the Servlet.