# Form POST produces wrong accented letters - JSP, Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, utf-8

I've followed so many indications 
(One of them is this checklist: [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps))
that I just surrended to the situation..

I have a form inside a JSP (that is then merged with a generic layout .tag)
When the post is executed, all accented letters are displayed in a wrong way, here an example:

è ò à ù ì é -> Ã¨ Ã² Ã Ã¹ Ã¬ Ã©

**I've checked the encoding in the browser's console, and is UTF-8.. Same inside a TestFilter I've added.. same inside the controller.
All the Symbols, are displayed correctly, the problem is just related to accented letters.. it's like the POST language is wrong, but I honestly have not found anything helpful online in 3 days.. THANKS A LOT**

- I've configured URIEncoding="UTF-8" in the Connectors inside server.xml (I'm using Tomcat9)
- I've set the: `<jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` inside the jsp
- I've added the `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />` in the head of the general .tag layout and the `<%@tag description="Overall Page template" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` declarative
- I've configured this unique filter in web.xml
- I've passed to the JSV `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` this parameter.

  ````
      <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>encoding</param-name>
          <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>```
  ````

This is the JSP, until the end of the interested FORM

```
    <jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:tags="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags"
          xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt">

    <tags:genericpage>
        <jsp:attribute name="header">
            <title><spring:message code="expenses.counter.page.title"/></title>
            <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/footer.css" />
        </jsp:attribute>
        <jsp:body>
            <jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1 class="text-center">EXPENSE COUNTER</h1>
                        <hr/>
                        <form id="expForm" action="/expCounter" method="post" class="needs-validation" accepted-charset="UTF-8" novalidate="">
                            <div class="form-row mx-5 my-4 text-center">
                                <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
                                <div class="form-group col-4 text-uppercase">
                                    <label for="description">
                                        <p><spring:message code="expenses.counter.description"/></p>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control ${validationResult.hasFieldErrors('description') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}" id="description" name="description"  />
                                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                                        <small><spring:message code="expenses.counter.error.description"/></small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- AMOUNT -->
                                <div class="form-group col-2 text-uppercase">
                                    <label for="amount">
                                        <p><spring:message code="expenses.counter.amount"/></p>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control ${validationResult.hasFieldErrors('amount') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}" id="amount" name="amount" required=""/>
                                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                                        <small><spring:message code="expenses.counter.error.amount"/></small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- DATE -->
                                <div class="form-group col-2 text-uppercase">
                                    <label for="spentOnDate">
                                        <p><spring:message code="expenses.counter.txdate"/></p>
                                    </label>
                                    <spring:message code="expenses.placeholder.ondate" var="ondate.placeholder" />
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control ${validationResult.hasFieldErrors('spentOnDate') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}" id="spentOnDate" name="spentOnDate" placeholder="${ondate.placeholder}" required=""/>
                                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                                        <small><spring:message code="expenses.counter.error.spentOnDate"/></small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- BUTTON -->
                                <div class="form-group col-2 align-self-end">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                        <spring:message code="general.button.submit"/>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is the generic .tag layout, until the body start:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@attribute name="header" fragment="true" %>
<%@attribute name="footer" fragment="true" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<html>
    <head>
<%--        <meta charset="utf-8"/>--%>
<%--        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>--%>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/footer.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/main.css">
        <jsp:invoke fragment="header"/>
    </head>
<body>
```

This is the method in the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/expCounter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addExpense(@Valid @ModelAttribute("expForm") Expense expense,
                             BindingResult result,
                             ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("validationResult", result);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("expForm", expense);
            return "redirect:expCounter";
        }

        expenseService.save(expense);
        return "redirect:expCounter";
    }
```

Comment: One item I don't see mentioned, which has helped me in the past: When you start Tomcat (i.e. when you start the JVM in which Tomcat runs), do you specify the `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` option? How you do this depends on how you start Tomcat. I mostly use a `setenv` file - see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) for notes. And see additional discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding).

Comment: Thank you about that. I forgot to mention it, but unfortunately yes. I pass the option in the Intellij config.. I'll edit my question adding this particular. 
Anyway I do not know what else to try.

Comment: SOLUTION: Hi... after have tried everything regardin UTF-8... I just tried a couple of minutes ago, to change from UTF-8 to charset=ISO-8859-1 in JSP page and the general layout .tag ....
Now accented letters are displayed fine! 

I decided to try this, because in a filer I added the encoding was alreay set on request/response and was UTF-8.. then I tested a conversion from charset=ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 with online converter and it seemed the problem..
So much time thrown away..

Comment: Glad you solved this - finally. Congratulations! You are welcome to write your own answer to your question - and to accept that answer, too. It makes the answer much more visible - and you may save someone else a lot of time, this way, also.

Comment: (I am so used to having everything always be _UTF-8 everywhere_ - I forget there are many other character encodings.)